# hibernate changing cfg properties at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to change cfg properties at runtime.
For example:

```
cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url")
```

The problem is that it works only when this property is not defined in the cfg file itself,
meaning, it doesn't override.

Can it be done in some way?

Comment: My guess is your are setting this property which is overrided by configuration file, there is nothing in hibernate code that suggests otherwise. Can you verify this?

Comment: I checked the hibernate code. The Configuration class has a member of Properties type. when we call configure, this member is initialized. if we call setProperty, the property we set is overridden. my mistake was that i first called setProperty and then called configure().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you run

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
```

the `.configure()` reads the data from the XML, and it has a higher priority over the programmatic configuration.

However, if you remove the `.configure`, all the configuration will be "read" from the settings that you will pass. For example:

```
       Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
       .setProperty( "hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver" )
       .setProperty( "hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect")
       [...snip...]
       .addAnnotatedClass( com.myPackage.MyClass.class )
       [...] ;
```

will set all the properties at runtime.

Comment: not quite. my problem was that i called cfg.configure(configFile) after i used setProperty. if I first configure, and then call setProperty, it takes the properties i set.

Comment: I've had some issues with .configure().setProperty() in one line. why I decided to completely abstract from hardocding info.

Comment: when it was typed `.configure().setProperty()`, the `.configure()` had some precedence over the `.setProperty`, so I wan't always having the desired behavior. I believe that if it is separated, it should work properly.