# Update Springboot properties at runtime Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I need to update the config `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` for one of my test classes. It should remain as `update` for all classes except one.

How do I achieve this at run time when session is being managed by Springboot?
Or is there some other way out?
I had the option to create a session afresh and use it as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437153/hibernate-changing-cfg-properties-at-runtime) but session is not managed manually.

Comment: What about `@TestPropertySource`? You can use it like this on your test class: `@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none")`

Comment: Well. Thank u so much @DmitrySenkovich . It works for me. Just setting thid annotation at the top of the class that need to have exclusive behaviour. Here's a related link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633638/testpropertsource-and-propertysource-dont-work-for-junit .

Comment: oh, that's nice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, simply adding `@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none")` on a test class should work. That's all:)